# Is is possible to pass logs to ELK stack via a ZeroMQ connection?

Tags: logstash, elk

I have just started learning about the ELK stack. I know that Logstash can take input from several different sources via filebeat client and put that in ElasticSearch.
Is it possible to pass log data to ELK via a ZeroMQ connection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a (community-maintained) [Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-zeromq.html) for elasticsearch to handle ZeroMQ input. Just give it a try and report back your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Logstash can read data from various message brokers (e.g. [ZeroMQ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-zeromq.html), [Kafka](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html), [RabbitMQ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html)).

There is a detailed [Blogpost](http://blog.lusis.org/blog/2012/02/06/zeromq-and-logstash-part-1/) on how to get messages from ZeroMQ into Logstash and the other way around.

Comment: the year 2018, logstash dropped support for ZeroMQ :(